# Compilation fails when using super in string concatination

Tags: java, inheritance, tostring

I have the following class, which doesn't compile:

```
public class C {
    public String toString() {
        return "Test " + super;
    }
}
```

It gives the the compilation error `Syntax error on token "super", invalid Expression`.

Does anyone know, why this compiler error occurs? The intended effect would be `"Test " + super.toString()`, which is compiling fine, but why does the example above fail to compile? Shouldn't the normal Java rules for String concatinations apply here?

Even more surprising that the following code compiles fine:

```
public String toString2() {
    return "Test " + this;
}
```

So why does `this`work in string concatination while `super` doesn't?

I'm using `openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16`, just in case it matters (which I doubt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `super` by itself is not a valid Java expression.  The summary of the answer is that `super` simply isn't used that way in Java.

The following types of expressions are the Java grammar productions including `super`, none of which present `super` by itself:

- [Field Access Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11)

  - `super . Identifier` This form accesses superclass members.
  - `TypeName . super . Identifier` This form accesses superclass members of the enclosing class.
- [Method Invocation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

  - `super . Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )` This form calls a superclass method.
  - `TypeName . super . Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )` This form calls either a superinterface method, or a superclass method in an enclosing class, depending on whether `TypeName` is a class name or an interface name.
- [Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)

  - `super :: Identifier`
  - `TypeName . super :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`

By contrast, `this` by itself is an expression, because it is allowed by itself to form a [primary expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8).  The keyword `super` by itself is not in this list of productions or in the sub-productions.  Think of a "primary" as the basic building block of an expression.

> Primary:
>
> PrimaryNoNewArray
>
> ArrayCreationExpression
>
> PrimaryNoNewArray:
>
> Literal
>
> ClassLiteral
>
> `this`
>
> TypeName . `this`
>
> `(` Expression `)`
>
> ClassInstanceCreationExpression
>
> FieldAccess
>
> ArrayAccess
>
> MethodInvocation
>
> MethodReference

The keyword `this` works in an expression because it's a Primary, which can participate in bigger, more complicated expressions involving operators such as `+`.

To summarize, `super` is only involved in larger productions to refer to specific ways of accessing the superclass.  The keyword `this`, while it can be involved in larger productions, is allowed by itself as a primary expression, which allows it to participate in more complicated expressions using operators.

Answer (score 2):

The `super` keyword in Java is not an **object reference** and thus you receive some errors in your code!
It's not a good practice to doing that so, Because `super` is a keyword to discover the **parent class**. So you can't print using that keyword!

According to Java spec :

> The forms using the keyword super are valid only in an instance
>   method, instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of
>   an instance variable of a class. If they appear anywhere else, a
>   compile-time error occurs.

Comment: As far as I know, it is an object reference to `this` being casted into the parent class type.

I'm also not sure how the paragraph you quoted answers my question, as I am using super in an instance method.

Comment: super is not a normal object, this can be used on its own. super cannot.

Answer (score 2):

`super` usages:

1. The statement `super()` is used to call the parent constructor and
   can be invoked only from the child's constructor. It also must be
   the first statement in the child's constructor.
2. super.instance_variable
3. super.instance_method

Eg:

```
class Animal {
    String name;
    Animal() { }

    String myName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    Dog() {
        super();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Test " + super.myName() + super.name;
    }
}
```

There is no standalone usage for *just* `super`. The `this` refers to the current object and can be invoked on its own.

Comment: I'm not talking about `super()` in a constructor call, but about using `"Test " + super` in a method call. I cannot use `this` in my example because it would lead to infinite recursion.

Comment: There is no usage for *just* super.

Comment: @DorianGray you have two answers by now explaining to you that using super isn't possible like that. The real question is: what is your toString method supposed to do?!

Comment: Well, it would be supposed to be equivalent to `"Test " + super.toString()` in the exaple above.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: "super" can't be used in that way.

That keyword can be used to either call a super constructor or to reference a super method/field. But it can't stand "all by its own".

As there is no "super" object. You can use "this" to reference the "this" object, but as there is no "standalone" super object. So the language does not allow you to use "super" the way you can use "this".

Comment: Well, it isn't a standalone object, but from what I've learned, it is merely equivalent to a cast of `this` to the parent class type, which forces the compiler to call the parent class method.

Comment: @DorianGray I suggest you revisit that topic. Either your source is wrong or you are misreading it.

Comment: Well, from 15.11.2. Accessing Superclass Members using super

    The form super.Identifier refers to the field named Identifier of the current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of the superclass of the current class.

I thought, "viewed as" is pretty much the same as "casted into"..

Also, Further below it states in the example: : Within class T3, the expression super.x is treated as if it were: ((T2)this).x